# Azure PHP Application and Azure SQL Database

Tags: php, azure, azure-sql-database

I have a PHP application on Azure and I want this application to connect to Azure SQL Database.

```
$servername = "AZURE.database.windows.net";
$username = "user";
$password = "pass";
$dbname = "DB";

$conn= mssql_connect($servername,$username,$password, $dbname);

$sql = "INSERT INTO AOL (AgentId,FullName, Email)
VALUES ('1', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')";


mssql_query($sql, $conn);
mssql_close($conn);
```

When I run this php script I get a 500 error.

Do you have experience with PHP on Azure and Azure SQL Database? Or must setting something on Azure for Azure SQL Database?

Comment: do you use Sql Azure? if so, make sure you have config your firewall rules to allow your site to connect to it.

Comment: yes, i using azure sql and firewall has rules for my websites :/

Comment: What format are you using for username? Also, for clarification, since you're connecting to SQL Database service (and not MS SQL Server), I changed the tagging accordingly.

Comment: What does your table definition (especially column types) look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, Azure environment doesn't install php_mssql.dll extension, it installs php_sqlsrv.dll instead.

You can use sqlsrv() instead:

```
$serverName = "<servername>.database.windows.net, 1433"; //serverName\instanceName
$connectionInfo = array("Database" => "<database_name>", "UID" => "<userid>", "PWD" => "<passowrd>");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);

if ($conn) {
    echo "Connection established.<br />";

    $query = sprintf("SELECT 1 as test");
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query);
    if ($stmt === false) {
        die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }

    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        print_r($row);
    }

    sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);

} else {
    echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```